# php get mysql data and display in <select>

Tags: php, mysql

I´m trying to get which option is in the databse from a `<select>`, here is my code:

```
<select name="category" value="<?php echo $category ?>" class="form-control">
    <option value="perros">Perro</option>
    <option value="gatos">Gato</option>
    <option value="peces">Pez</option>
    <option value="aves">Ave</option>
    <option value="reptiles">Reptil</option>
    <option value="roedores">Roedor</option>
    <option value="productos">Producto</option>
</select>
```

my PHP:

```
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ID=$id")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

 if($row)
 {

 $category = $row['category'];
```

the problem is that it shows the first `<option>` i have. Thank you

Whole code: http://pastebin.com/2jBjt3SD

Comment: Take out `value="<?php echo $category ?>"`. This is open to SQL injections as well.

Comment: it´s a private page, so that wouldn´t be a problem

Comment: What is the relation between your PHP and form? Where does `id` come in? Also that could still be an issue, if your values ever contain a `'` this won't work..

Comment: The id comes from the filename, it fetches it with a _GET['']:
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0)

Comment: Can you show more of the PHP code, not sure I'm following you? Does the PHP generate that HTML?

Comment: Can you echo the `$category` outside the select and check what it returns?

Comment: Do you want to check if selected item in the database or check for all the items?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes $category outputs what i have in the database, "perros"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the selected option of a `<select>` you have to put the `selected` attribute on the correct option. Something like

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
    <option <?php echo $category=='perros'?'selected':'' ?> value="perros">Perro</option>
    <option <?php echo $category=='gatos'?'selected':'' ?>value="gatos">Gato</option>
    <option <?php echo $category=='peces'?'selected':'' ?>value="peces">Pez</option>
    <option <?php echo $category=='aves'?'selected':'' ?>value="aves">Ave</option>
    <option <?php echo $category=='perros'?'selected':'' ?>value="reptiles">Reptil</option>
    <option <?php echo $category=='roedores'?'selected':'' ?>value="roedores">Roedor</option>
    <option <?php echo $category=='productos'?'selected':'' ?>value="productos">Producto</option>
</select>
```

you could use a loop to make it cleaner though

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there's no shortcut for this. You need to set it like,

```
<select name="category" class="form-control">
    <option value="perros" <?php $category == 'perros' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Perro</option>
    <option value="gatos" <?php $category == 'gatos' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Gato</option>
    <option value="peces" <?php $category == 'peces' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Pez</option>
    <option value="aves" <?php $category == 'aves' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Ave</option>
    <option value="reptiles" <?php $category == 'reptiles' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Reptil</option>
    <option value="roedores" <?php $category == 'roedores' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Roedor</option>
    <option value="productos" <?php $category == 'productos' ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>Producto</option>
</select>
```

Or, if you use jQuery, you have an alternative approach like,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var catVal = <?php echo $category; ?>;
        $('select[name=category]').val(catVal);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the select and id and assign it a value with javascript like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('your_id').vaue = <?php echo $category; ?>;
</script>
```